# I'm pulling my hair out with basic error

Tags: php, loops

I think i'm to old or i'm just stupid but i can't understand why i can't loop on an simple array.

I have this code:

```
$results = [];
for ($i = 0; $i < count($links); $i++) {
   $results[] = [
      'site' => $links[$i],
      'pda'  => $data[$i]->pda
   ];
}
```

The $links array contains a list of urls and $data contains a list of values like this:

```
array(3) {
  0 =>  object(stdClass) 
    {
      "pda" => int 100
    }
  1 =>  object(stdClass) 
    {
      "pda" => int 100
    }
  2 =>  object(stdClass) 
    {
      "pda" => int 1
    }
}
```

EDIT: This is the print_r($data) content...it seems that some of you don't understand the dump from above and prefer the print_r solution :-|

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pda] => 100
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pda] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pda] => 100
        )

)
```

If i do $data[$i]->pda in the loop i get "Cannot use object of type stdClass as array" error.

If i try to access it as an object, i get "Trying to get property of non-object" error.

Bottom line, am i stupid or i'm going crazy?!

Thank you!

Comment: Can you try `print_r($data)` and post the output?

Comment: `Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [pda] => 1 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [pda] => 100 ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [pda] => 100 ) )`

Comment: Can you show us what output you want to achieve?

Comment: Don't tell me that is not logic from the loop above?!
I just asked a simple question to a problem that beats me.
How could you access the pda object from the array if not with $data[0] or $data[$i]->pda in my case?
I have 5+ years of php programming and this is just....

Comment: @RobertChabal I absolutely don't find anything wrong with `$data[$i]->pda`. Sorry can't help you there. Maybe show the full code?

Comment: I could show you the full code but it has no relevance.
The code is part of a bigger system...$data is a call to a method that makes some API request and many other things.
The bottom line is that $data contains that dump of array.
I just don't get it...why it throws me that error on calling $data[$i]->pda - beats me.

Comment: what is $links?

Comment: @Gaura Srivastava is an array of 3 links like this:

`array(3) {
      0 => string(16) "www.facebook.com"
      1 => string(15) "www.codefish.ro"
      2 => string(15) "www.twitter.com"
 }`

Comment: Maybe you have a different number of `$links` than `$data`. Create a `if else` statement to check if `$data[$i]` is available before assigning it to your result and if not dump it. Maybe your function (guessing its inside one) gets called several times with data you are not expecting and dumping your data the first time gives you a correct result?

Comment: @enricog please make / repost your comment as an answer.
The $link returned a fourth key with a null value.
That's why the loop fails on the $data objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Little bit extended answer from comments:

You probably have a different number of `$links` than `$data`.
Debug with a simple `if else` condition before accessing `$data[$i]` and dump the actual result if it fails.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < count($links); $i++) {
  if (isset($data[$i])) {
      $results[] = [
       'site' => $links[$i],
       'pda'  => $data[$i]->pda
    ];
  } else {
    // Somethings wrong
    var_dump($i);
    var_dump($links);
    var_dump($data);
  }

}
```

So if your function gets called several times, you are dumping the actual data when the error happens.

Answer (score -1):

According to your structure:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pda] => 100
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pda] => 1
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [pda] => 100
        )

)
```

And your calling structure:

```
$data[$i]->pda
```

Here you call in wrong way, $i is not array its a stdclass object array, try by this:

```
$data->$i['pda'].
```

By this $data watching into your stdclass object array and then "pda" calls as an array for that.

Comment: pda is an object not array so the first call is the right one $data[$i]->pda not $data->$i['pda]

Comment: Can you please try my syntax and check you get error.

Comment: It's absurd...basic loop iteration.
Your example is wrong.

Comment: @Robert if "pda" is std class array and "$i" is array then your code works but it is not working that means there is error in your calling. Did you try my syntax?

Comment: My friend, do you see the dump data above?
That is [array]->object not object[array] as you suggest.
The problem was solved.
The $link array returned a fourth key with a nulled value.